# Azure VM : SQL servers on machines should have vulnerability findings resolved

Tags: azure

I have created a Windows VM in Azure and this VM don't have SQL installed.

However, I see the following compliance issue

> SQL servers on machines should have vulnerability findings resolved

[image]

How do I fix this compliance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the results successfully like below:***

To Fix this Non- compliance issue:

***In your VM -> under setting, Microsoft defender for clouds -> you can see vulnerability finding resolved like below:***

[image]

Double click on it, SQL servers on machines should have vulnerability findings resolved screen will display like below:

[image]

Click on Machines should have vulnerability findings resolved there you have seen description of issue and you can see Remediation steps to fix the issue of your machine like below:

[image]

Each recommendation has its own set of instructions. In my case I have unhealthy resource in my machine try check your remediation steps of SQL server in below reference and quick fix.

***Reference***:

[Enable Vulnerability Assessment on SQL Servers with Azure Policy](https://charbelnemnom.com/enable-vulnerability-assessment-on-sql-servers/)   by *charbel nemnom*

[azure-docs/defender-for-sql-on-machines-vulnerability GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-sql-on-machines-vulnerability-assessment.md)

[Security Control: Remediate Vulnerabilities - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-cloud/security-control-remediate-vulnerabilities/ba-p/1430971)